# Was Tirupati Balaji a Buddhist Shrine?

Tags: temples

I had read occasionally on internet that [Tirupati Balaji](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=v9bsWODMNKfT8geD94_QAw&gws_rd=ssl#q=tirupati+balaji+) was a Buddhist Shrine. So Was Tirupati Balaji a Buddhist Shrine ?

Comment: FYI, unlike the policy on other SE sites, posting questions so that you can self-answer them is discouraged on this site: [May I share my research, by posting questions on this site and self-answering them?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1784/254)

Comment: Downvoted , please follow @ChrisW suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a book by K. Jamanadas "[Tirupati Balaji was a Buddhist Shrine](http://www.satnami.com/Tirupati%20a%20buddhist%20srine.pdf)", whose preface starts with,

> [This book] has potential credibility to create
>   controversies unknown to historical writing and the Hindu common folks who flock to worship Tirupati Balaji
>   as one of the supreme deities. It is also a new challenge to indologist at a time when politically imbued
>   scholars are engaged to wash out their hands by proving and disproving claims of Hindus and the Muslims
>   against each other as they did over the issue of Ayodhya Shrines.

Its conclusion is that

> The image of Lord Venkatesvara was not sculptured by the artist as an image of Vishnu, but that of
>   Avalokitesvara, sometimes in the reign of Kalabhras, after the period of Mamulanur, and before the period of
>   Silappadhikaran, around 3rd to 5th century A.D.

Comment: This is a copy-and-paste of http://creative.sulekha.com/dr-k-jamanadas-proves-tirupati-temple-as-a-buddhist-shrine_295854_blog or some other similar source. Please read my comment on Ajay's answer, and edit your answer to reference+quote+summarize like I edited Ajay's answer.

Answer (score -1):

The article "[Is Tirupati Balaji Temple a Buddist Temple](https://controversialhistory.blogspot.fr/search/label/Silapthikaram)" concludes that it wasn't:

> ### Conclusion
>
> The Conclusion is that the Tirupati is a Vishnu temple all along. Since the temple has been built around 9th century AD. It is after 9th century AD that the hill is said to be holy place. So any account which says that the hill is holy(sri or Thiru venkata) is after 9th century AD. This applies any work or devote singing on Tirupati. The dispute seems to be primarily between Shivite and Vaishnavite, because of the Shiva Temple at the base of Tirupati which predate the Tirupati temple. Indologist seems to have introduced some confusion here. There are no inscriptions about Tripati temple, before 9th century AD, because the temple did not exist then, not because it was a Buddhist Shrine.

Its arguments are:

- The expression "Dig underneath every Hindu temple, there will be a Buddhist temple" is rhetoric, not always true (some new temples are built on new sites)
- The historical record (including the puranas) isn't clear
- Early (Buddhist) temples were rock-cut, whereas this is a standalone temple
- The earliest inscription mentioning this place mentions a hill but not a temple. The earliest inscription in the temple is from 830 AD.

Comment: @Swapnil just scroll down the Wikipedia article and see what your religion says. Your question how it is possible when Ramayana is only mythological is an assumption that it is not true. But your previous Buddhas before siddharata Gautama were also from Ramayana characters. If Buddha is against brahmins then why there is a concept of Maitreya Buddha? So no conflict existed between Buddha and brahmin. It is a myth created during 20th century

Comment: @Swapnil https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_named_Buddhas You can clearly see all of the previous Buddhas are either Brahmins or Kshatriyas. 

Also 

 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ikshvaku_dynasty#In_Buddhist_tradition

Comment: This answer is a copy-and-paste of the whole of https://controversialhistory.blogspot.fr/search/label/Silapthikaram (posted in 2011). Please read the answers to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/139866 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/139866 -- the way to fix this is to 1) Delete this answer 2) Write an answer of your own, which a) Includes a link to the reference you want to quote b) Is a summary of the reference (or a summary of the reasoning in the reference), written in your own words c) Quotes one or more fragments from the linked reference (using block-quote formatting).

Comment: @ChrisW The author and me are friends. Anyhow, I will provide link